# Electronic toy from the early 2000s where you push back in elements that pop out

Tags: identify-this-game, chip

I'm hoping this question belongs here as this is the closest site I could find that matched my situation.

Many years ago, around late 2003 or 2004, I came across this electronic toy that sort of functioned like a Bop It or Torx. It was dubbed the Face Bop It because it resembled the shape of a face on a pie. The top part consisted of a hat or a head with convex lined ridges representing hair. One ear had a rubber duck antenna attached to it. The nose felt more like the hands of a clock that sprang anticlockwise, and the mouth opened to make a smiley face.

The objective of the game was to pop in any of these components or turn the nose whenever they popped out. If you took too long, or if one of the parts were jammed, it would make a low buzzing sound and make three 'twew-twew-twew' sounds.

Unfortunately, since I am completely blind, I could not identify any writing on the back, nor would I be able to identify it based on images. I'm hoping someone here knows what this toy is and can send me information about what it's officially called, who made it, and any more information that would prove useful.

Comment: When I googled it, I found an Amazon link to Hasbro Pie Face. Is this the same one in the answer? https://www.amazon.com/Hasbro-B7063-Pie-Face-Game/dp/B010F029Y4

Comment: No; the description is *Hilarious Pie Face game might just splat you in the face
Pie-throwing arm could go off at any moment
Score a point every time you turn the handle without getting splatted
Includes 1 pie thrower, 1 throwing arm, 2 handles, chin rest, splash guard mask, spinner and sponge.
Slide your head through the mask and watch out*

Comment: The play action reminds me of Whack-a-mole, an arcade game.  I never heard of a home game based on whack-a-mole, but this game fills the gap.

Answer (score 8):

The [Hasbro Heads Up](https://toysit.com/heads-up-game-toy/) from 2000 seems to match your description. Its right ear (on your left as you face it) resembles a rubber duck antenna, and the other ear looks like some kind of knob or the mouthpiece of a trumpet. The hair consists of 4 ridges on the hairpiece.

Comment: Yes, that is the one. Actually, both ears look like a knob, but its right ear, or the left as you face it, has the antenna on the upper part of it.